# Post method is getting bytes instead of json data

Tags: python, jquery, api

I am making a post request from jquery to create an article in my blog.

```
//Responsible for creating an article 
$('#create-article').click(function(e){
    title = $('#input-title').val()
    description = $('#input-desc').val() 
    data = {title, description}
    $.post('/blog/create/', data, 'json')
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

The View below is responsible for printing out the POST response. According to my POST submission, it should print out a json response but it is printing out a Python bytes. why is it happening?

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_article(request):
    if request.POST:
        print(request.body)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

**Printing:** b'title=hello+&description=world+there'

**Expecting:** {'title': 'hello', 'description': 'world there'}

What should i do to get the expected result?

Comment: try `json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: JSON is just a protocol for what should be contained in the `bytes` object. When you decode it using `json.loads(request.body)` or `request.json()`, you get a Python dictionary represented by the JSON bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Even though you are specifying that you are expecting the server to return JSON in the AJAX call, you still need to handle the return of JSON on the backend.  Right now `request.body` just returns whatever Python's default it, which isn't JSON.

```
import json

@csrf_exempt
def create_article(request):
    if request.POST:
        print 'Content-Type: application/json\n'
        print(json.dumps(request.body))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```